# How to convert PDF byte[] to String and String to PDF byte[]

Tags: java

In my web application, as per the requirement I need to print PDF file to laser printer without opening windows default "Print" popup.

So here I am using applet to print the bytes which are stored in HTML text area.

But it seems that the bytes generated after new String(pdf.getByte[]) is different than the actual PDF bytes.

In my controller I am storing  the  bytes to request scope as mentioned below :

```
request.setAttribute(PageRenderConstant.MULTI_SEL_PDF,new String(printOutputVO.getPdfBytes()));
```

And in HTML ... I am storing the byte as below ..

```
<textarea style="visibility: hidden;"  name="laserPrintData"  id="laserPrintData" >
   ${multiselpdffile}                   
</textarea>
```

And here is the applet code to print the document to laser pritner...

```
function print(){                                                           
  var applet = document.jZebra;
  if (applet != null) {    
  var data = $("#laserPrintData").val();
  //applet.append(data);
  applet.appendPDF(data);              
  applet.printPS();
  }
}
```

But it says "The provided PDF is corrupted file." So the bytes after new String() operation are different.

So How can I retain the same bytes as it was before new String() operation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Base64 methods to convert byte[] to String and decode it back to byte[]

```
public static byte[] decode(String encoded)
public static String encode(byte[] binaryData) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have used 64 bit encoder and decoder. For encoding I am using sun.misc.BASE64Encoder on my controller. And on Client side I am using JQuery 64 bit decoder. But its not working. The JQuery decoder is not decoding the String That is encoded by sun.misc.BASE64Encoder. Can you have any idea why its not supporting ???

Comment: @GunjanShah you can check how Encoder creates the string and implement own decoding. See for example code of the decode method of sun's lib.

Comment: ohk...It was the  problem with Decoder.Now I am using apache.codec.Base64 encoder. Now it works fine. Thanks.